# Play Background Audio using Turbo Native Android

Tags: android, turbolinks, background-audio

I'm developing an app for a radio station using Turbo from a website also using Turbo but I'm experiencing a problem with background audio streaming. When the screen is turned off or the user uses other apps, the audio eventually stops playing.

Is there a way to keep it playing?